# Жерло — в значении "дуло" (автомата или пистолета). Правильно ли?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, словосочетания

Нередко в книгах встречаются словосочетания: ***жерло*** автомата или ***жерло*** пистолета.
Разве корректна такая формулировка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В толковом словаре Ефремовой "прописано" четко:
[**жерло́**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Efremova-term-23964.htm), ср.
***1.*** Переднее отверстие ствола огнестрельного орудия; **дуло.**
2. а) узкое и глубокое отверстие;
б) входное отверстие печи;
в) отверстие в вулканической горе, кратере вулкана.

Так что все правильно.

*Только тут Нойбауэр увидел направленное прямо на него темное **жерло автомата*** (Эрих Мария Ремарк. Искра жизни).

*Потом ему вспомнилось заслонившее весь мир черное **жерло пистолета**, глянувшее вдруг прямо в глаза и, казалось, в самую душу; вспомнился собственный испуг при виде этой черной дыры в небытие — испуг, который заставил его торопливо спустить курок* (А. Н. Воронин. Русская княжна Мария).

Answer (score 1):

Да, корректна, это одно из значений слова.

Вот в одном из словарей:

> жерло-а́, мн. же́рла, жерл, ср. **Узкое, глубокое или горлообразное
>   отверстие.** Жерло вулкана. □ [Полковник] был на вершине Пектусана и
>   даже спускался в его озеро, помещенное на глубине 1.300 футов в жерле
>   бывшего кратера. Гарин-Михайловский, По Корее, Маньчжурии и
>   Ляодунскому полуострову.
>
> || Входное отверстие печи. То и дело худые,
>    цепкие руки [рабочих] набирали полную лопатку угля и затем быстрым,
>   ловким движением всовывали его в раскрытое пылающее жерло. Куприн,
>   Молох.
>
> || **Дуло, переднее отверстие ствола артиллерийского орудия.** На
>   платформах стояли орудия. Чехлы с них были сдернуты, и орудийные жерла
>   смотрели в небо. Чаковский, Это было в Ленинграде. В третий раз
>   навязчиво гудящий, как комар, катер появился перед жерлами береговых
>   батарей. Чернышев, На морском охотнике.
>
> Малый академический словарь. — М.: Институт русского языка Академии
>   наук СССР Евгеньева А. П. 1957—1984

http://endic.ru/academic/Zherlo-4713.html

Answer (score 1):

> Вы сотни лет глядели на Восток,
>
> Копя и плавя наши перлы,
>
> И вы, глумясь, считали только срок,
>
> Когда наставить **пушек жерла**!

*(А. А. Блок, [«Скифы»](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%8B_(%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA)))*